# Why does SVM predict only one class (when having two classes), even on train_data?

Tags: python, classification, svm, prediction

I have a dataset, with "probabilities" (X), "results" (y) and "loss" (z).
X contains the probabilities of classifications. The highest probabilities of each array will be chosen. For each array, there is a corresponding 'loss' value and 'result' value. But sometimes this classification is not correct. This is represented by the results in y. `1`=correct classification, `0`=wrong classification.

I want to predict those result for another dataset (test_data).

`X` looks like this (5461 lines):

```
[[  7.52080159e-05   3.52246707e-06   9.99919772e-01   1.60897298e-06]
 [  5.29095473e-07   1.37183363e-07   9.99999166e-01   6.71615084e-08]
 [  8.79671461e-06   3.60849692e-04   4.20530778e-05   9.99588311e-01]
 [...]]
```

Overall, there are only 33 `0`, the rest are `1`. And also, the probabilities are quite high (ca. 95% and higher).

Still, I'd like to predict the results correctly. In fact, even when I test it with my train_data, the SVM only returns `1`. No matter if there should be `0`.
E.g. for `X[29]` the result is `0`. But the prediction returns `1`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

f = np.load('analyse.npy', encoding='latin1', fix_imports=True)
test_file = np.load('test.npy', encoding='latin1', fix_imports=True)

X = np.array(f.item()['probabilities'])
X = X.reshape(-1,4)

print(X[:3])

y = np.array(f.item()['result'])

print(list(y))

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear');
clf = clf.fit(X, y)

pred = clf.predict(X)
print(list(pred))

print(X[29])
print(y[29])
```

Output:
[image: Output]

What am I missing here? I relatively new to SVM. First I wanted to skip the 'loss' values, but it seems, I need it, right? Since the probabilities are very high, to I have to scale/normalize them?

Comment: Depending on your data size, this is class-imbalance problem. Lets say if in 100 samples, 95 belong to 1 and 5 to 0, then by predicting all to 1, the classifier is having 95% accuracy. Please add more details about your dataset, and try something to handle the imbalance.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for your reply. This explanation seems reasonable to me. I was also thinking that way. I guess, I should try adding more Arrays with class `0` as a noise/rebalancing?

There's not much to tell about the data. The big picture here is image classification. Picture 1 (array 1) can be classified as one of four classes (my four probabilities). The highest proba will be chosen as the class. But this could be wrong. (result = 1 -> classification correct | result = 0 -> classification not correct.
There are 5461 samples, 33 not correct, 5428 correct.

Hope this helps a bit.